# Azure KeyVault: how to retrieve clientId, clientSecret and the tenantId for an existing Service Principal?

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk-python, service-principal

The cloud engineer in my organization has set up an Azure KeyVault and a Service Principal. I know the id of this Service Principal, but I also need `clientId`, `clientSecret`, and `tenantId`.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-python?tabs=cmd) shows that these variables are exposed to you when you create a Service Principal using Azure CLI, but in my case, there is one already. I don't have the credentials to create a new one, and frankly speaking, I don't need to.

So, how can I retrieve the `clientId`, `clientSecret`, and `tenantId` associated with the existing Service Principal?

Comment: Client id and tenant id you can get, but client secret you cannot retrieve. It is shown once when the secret is created and can't be read from anywhere. You need a new secret if it is not available.

Comment: @juunas doesn't this mean that I need a new service principal to be created?

Comment: Just reset it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp/credential?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_sp_credential_reset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the Service Principal's `Client Id` and `Tenant Id` using CLI command like below:

```
az ad sp list --query "[].{id:appId, tenant:appOwnerTenantId}"
```

You can even get many more values of the Service Principals - refer to [ServicePrincipalInner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli#reset-credentials) class.

Further, as mentioned in the comments, you cannot retrieve the `Client Secret` created by somebody else. You will have to [reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli#reset-credentials) it:

```
az ad sp credential reset --name APP_ID
```